# SSRS Report last execution time for each report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 75 SSRS reports and I need to get each report latest (max) executed DateTime. Could you please help me with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the catalog and executionlog tables to get this information

```
SELECT 
    c.Name, c.[Path], MAX(e.TimeStart) as LastRun
 FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c 
    join ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog e on c.ItemID = e.ReportID
GROUP BY c.name, c.[Path]
```